# How do I get the Tomcat manager/status to work with my local hostname?

Tags: java, tomcat

This works http://localhost:8080/manager/status and this doesn't http://canalistan:8080/manager/status. The Tomcat home page displays OK with either localhost or canalistan (my hostname).

I've put an entry in the hosts file. I'm using Tomcat v7, Windows 7 etc. Everything else seems to work OK and I've even managed to set up a virtual host, but this has so far eluded me.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the host name aliases for your purpose? For an example if you are using tomcat 7 try this: [tomcat 7 host name aliases](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/host.html#Host_Name_Aliases)

Comment: The problem remains. I think there maybe other issues as I'm using XAMPP and have set up the manager-gui role with a user/password which doesn't give access to the manager, but adding the manager-gui role to the basic tomcat user/role does access the manager. So providing I use localhost and the tomcat role everything works fine. I'm missing something and I haven't figured it out yet.